# scrollToRowAtIndexPath is not working fine?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am using a tableview with autolayet corners set to (0,0,0,0).I had a custom cell set on the table view.my issue is the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` is not working fine.my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods is looking like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    RTableViewCell *cell = (RTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
       for (UIView *currentView in tableView.subviews) {
            if ([currentView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                ((UIScrollView *)currentView).delaysContentTouches = NO;
                break;
            }
        }
        UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        myBackView.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:216/255.0 green:231/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;

   return cell;      
}
```

i had dynamic number of sections and dynamic number of rows inside that.
and in my `viewDidAppear`  i am calling like this

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     //int indexValue = (int)[sections indexOfObject:string];
     [rtable reloaddata];
        NSIndexPath *rowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:6];
     [self.rtable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:rowIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
});
```

anybody knows where i am going wrong?

Comment: What's the expected outcome and what happens instead?

Comment: i wanted the tableview to be at 6th section in 0th row.but it is only scrolling up to 3 rd section .

Comment: Are you sure there are enough rows to allow scrolling to section 6 at positionTop?  You might need to add some bottom space via contentInset

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
[rtable reloaddata];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSIndexPath *rowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:6];
        [self.rtable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:rowIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

    });
```